# "reg add" Just doesn't seem to work sometime in .BAT files

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm writing a .BAT script that constantly updates the registry to make a sort of animated wallpaper. I split a gif image into .bmp images, and run it. Here is my code:

```
:funny
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,30) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\c" /f 
  reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\idk\images\frames\troll\frame_%%A_delay-0.05s.bmp" /f 
  reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperStyle /f
  reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /t REG_SZ /d 2 /f
  RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 
)

goto funny
```

For some reason, it only works sometimes, working for a second, stopping, starting when i hover over something then stopping again.. Any tips?(I don't have admin permissions by the way)

Comment: `constantly updates` is not really true, as fast as possible within a second is more realistic, much too fast. The desktop background image displaying feature is not designed for rapid changes and updates, i.e. the background __image__ displaying feature is designed for displaying an image and not an animation, video, etc. Why do you not use a multimedia viewer to show the animation?

Comment: An analogy to real world for better understanding. You buy a cheap car and think how funny it would be to drive with it faster than sound. So you get from somewhere a jet engine with fuel tanks, put all into the trunk of the car (more or less), take place behind the steering wheel of the car and ignite the turbine. What do you think will happen? I doubt that you will reach Mach 1 with the car. But some others watching your attempt would have perhaps fun.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just wasn't updating the screen fast enough. I now update the screen using C#.

```
write-host "hi, starting" 

$imgPath=$desktopImage
$code = @' 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
namespace Win32{ 
    
     public class Wallpaper{ 
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
         static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction , int uParam , string lpvParam , int fuWinIni) ; 
         
         public static void SetWallpaper(string thePath){ 
            SystemParametersInfo(20,0,thePath,3); 
         }
    }
 } 
'@

add-type $code 

#Apply the Change on the system 
for ($num = 0; $num -lt 60 ; $num++) {
    [Win32.Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper("C:\Users\user\Downloads\obama\frame_" + $num + "_delay-0.04s.jpg")
    if ($num -ge 59) {
        $num = 0;
    }
   # Start-Sleep -Seconds 0.3
}
```

Thanks for the analogy @Mofi, but who needs optimization when you can have [spinning obama sphere?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzXoX.gif)

Comment: (Joke, I understand. I'm on a school computer and have no other options.)